# Roll size and node performance

Tags: baking, node, roll, performance

Could someone explain in detail how the size of the roll (currently 10k xtz and one amendment proposal offers to reduce this to 8k xtz) impacts the node performance ?

This would be a great way to understand more accurately the pros and cons of reducing the roll size.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just asked that question at riot.
The answer from our very wise Adrian Brink:

[image]

Comment: thanks! I'll let you deal with Adrian for the attribution of this upvote ;) But one the bottom of this i have the same follow-up question: so that confirms that the only question at stake for node performance here is really the storage + io operations ? In that regard is 20% significant ? or do read/writes scale faster than linearly ?

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://medium.com/cryptium/dissecting-the-first-tezos-amendment-proposals-334555af9614) is a great article by CryptiumLabs that deals with these questions.

Comment: Thanks for the article it is interesting. However it does not really go into technical details enough. Is storage the only performance aspect at play ? What is roll storage ? Does it take a significant amount of space and therefore is a 20% increase really significant ?